# std::size_t Instantiation

Tags: c++

My first post, so please be kind  :)

This code snippet is from the Poco library project:

```
void SyslogParser::parse(const std::string& msg)
{
// <int> -> int: lower 3 bits severity, upper bits: facility
std::size_t pos = 0;
RemoteSyslogChannel::Severity severity;
RemoteSyslogChannel::Facility fac;
parsePrio(msg, pos, severity, fac);

// the next field decide if we parse an old BSD message or a new syslog message
// BSD: expects a month value in string form: Jan, Feb...
// SYSLOG expects a version number: 1

if (Poco::Ascii::isDigit(msg[pos]))
{
    parseNew(msg, severity, fac, pos);
}
else
{
    parseBSD(msg, severity, fac, pos);
}
poco_assert (pos == msg.size());
}
```

I do not understand the role of std::size_t here.  I thought that std::size_t would create an object (uint32 or uint64 depending on platform, etc.) which could hold the size of some other object.  Is this understanding correct?

So what is happening here, then, is, we are creating an uint and (it appears) using it as a bitfield.  If I am understanding what is being done, then I have to ask why?  What is the advantage of producing an uint this way, as opposed to just declaring one?

Not questioning the author, just trying to understand what the advantage might be to take this route.  Is there a speed or efficiency benefit?

Comment: The benefit of using size_t is for the programmer reading the code. The way to interpret size_t is that it denotes the size of things, like objects, or how many characters in a string, or an offset into some datastructure.

Answer (score 2):

*I thought that `std::size_t` would create an object (uint32 or uint64 depending on platform, etc.) which could hold the size of some other object. Is this understanding correct?*

Yes
`std::size_t` is a type that can be used to hold a size of any object in C/C++ program.

Usually functions use `std::size_t` type as a standard way of receiving size of an object/type as an function parameter. Since the poco library functions are using `std::size_t` as the type , the caller needs to create a parameter with the same type while calling these functions.

Answer (score 2):

I think the comment in line 3 is misleading and should be removed.

`pos`, as the name suggests, is the position in the string to which the string has been parsed already. At the end, the whole string must have been parsed, that's why all the `parse*` functions (possibly) increment that variable. There are no bitfields involved here.

Maybe you thought that creating an object of type `std::size_t` was an expensive operation, since many other types from that namespace are indeed possibly expensive, like `std::string`, `std::map`. But that isn't the case. `std::size_t` is a very cheap data type.

The code should really look like this:

```
void SyslogParser::parse(const std::string& msg)
{
  std::size_t pos = 0;

  // <int> -> int: lower 3 bits severity, upper bits: facility
  RemoteSyslogChannel::Severity severity;
  RemoteSyslogChannel::Facility fac;
  parsePrio(msg, pos, severity, fac);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the `parsePrio()` function takes the `pos` parameter by reference, so the calling code must use the exact same type the function is expecting.  Moreover, the `std::string::size()` function returns a value of type `std::string::size_type`, which is usually `std::size_t`.  Using the same type as the value being compared to is also a good thing.